# Split a word inside bash for loop?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to do a simple bash for loop to loop through my video and transcoded to a different format

```
for i in $(ls *.MTS); do encode -i $i -o $i.mp4; done
```

But the file output file currently looks like `00000.MTS.mp4`

How do I substitute the output variable so it looks like `00000.mp4`

Comment: Read the _fantastic_ manual to find more about [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: If you can't do any of the above, consider searching this site for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two equivalent solutions:

1. Remove the original extension with `%.MTS` and then append the new one:

   ```
   for file in *.MTS; do encode -i "$file" -o "${file%.MTS}.mp4"; done
   ```
2. Perform a search-and-replace:

   ```
   for file in *.MTS; do encode -i "$file" -o "${file/%MTS/mp4}"; done
   ```

   (The `%` here anchors the search to the end of the file name, in case it happens to contain the substring `MTS` elsewhere.)

Comment: QQ: Won't `"${file%.*}.mp4"` suffice?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.MTS; do encode -i "$i" -o "${i%.MTS}".mp4; done
```

- Don't use `ls` like that.
- Do use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).